# App Crashing After iOS9 Update, Won't Connect to Internet

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9

Can anyone help me out here, my app is crashing in iOS9, it was fine 2 weeks ago. New to Objective-C, need help.

When running the app in xCode I get this message

Terminating app due to uncaught exception'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch'

Comment: Your app doesn't have a root view controller. Either set it programmatically in the app delegate or check `is initial view controller` for the entry view controller in the storyboard.

Comment: Darn, I'm in a big pickle then, how do I set that up...

Comment: are you using storybaords?

Comment: No, I'm in a pretty simple wrapper app.

Answer (score 0):

Your app doesn't have a root view controller. Select the View Controller in the storyboard which is your entry point. Then in the Attributes Inspector check the box for `Is Initial View Controller`.

**OR**

in `application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`  method

```
UIViewController *vC = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"viewControllerID"]; 

self.window.rootViewController = vC;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

return YES;
```

If you are not using storyboards just instantiate the view controller with the init method.

Comment: pretty new at this, what is the init method?

Comment: `UIViewController *vC = [[UIViewController alloc] init];`

Comment: darn now I'm getting this error back, return UIApplicationMain( argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass( [AppDelegate class] ) );

Comment: You will need to instantiate the view controller class you created instead of UIViewController.